# Latent variable estimation with fixed effects

Tags: bayesian, factor-analysis, latent-variable, lavaan, stan

I have survey data on political beliefs that I'd like to estimate latent ideology with. Survey questions are binary agree/disagree responses. However, respondents can repeat the survey and skip any questions they want. As a result, I have variation across individuals in how many responses I have and which questions were answered. Some answered all questions once or twice, others answered the same few questions dozens of times.

If everyone had the same propensity to answer questions I might do some sort of SEM/factor analysis:

$$
y_i = v + \lambda\theta_i + \epsilon_i
$$
Where $y_i$ is the observed responses from person $i$, $v$ is the intercept, $\lambda$ is the factor loading, and $\theta$ is the latent ideology variable.

However, people have different participation rates for the survey and response rates for specific questions. I don't want to transform responses to a binary and use IRT because that sacrifices a lot of information. How do I incorporate these different response propensities into my latent variable estimation?

Is it something like a fixed/random effect to shift the intercept for each participant? I haven't seen any similar applications in latent variable software like Stan and Lavaan, is this possible?

Comment: IRT and CFA are equivalent - if you can do it in IRT you can do it in CFA (mostly). Why would dichotomization let you use IRT? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: My understanding is that standard IRT is primarily applied to dichotomous responses and that CFA is more suitable for continuous variables. I know there are variants of both suitable to different data types and I'm happy to use either.

My primary concern is that dichotomizing eliminates potentially valuable information and it's not clear to me how to specify a latent variable model that incorporates what are essentially different intercepts for each participant.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think dichotomization would be relevant to the missing responses, or what you mean by participants having individual intercepts.  Perhaps you are thinking of IRT models fitted to long-format data as mixed-effect models, in which the random intercept for subjects *is* the person parameter (theta_i in your equation above).  Regarding how to accommodate all your available information, are you aware of the FIML method available in SEM software?  It assumes data are MAR, which might need auxiliary variables to justify: https://web.pdx.edu/~newsomj/semclass/ho_missing.pdf

Comment: You can take a look at stan's [Finite Mixtures](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/latent-discrete-parameterization.html) models. You would have a simplex of your questions with categorical priors. Zero-inflated and hurdle models (from the same chapter as above) give you additional control over the unanswered questions with Poisson and Bernoulli pmf's as count data.